# Chrome 52 CSS issue with inline-block and columns

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, css-multicolumn-layout

After updating to Chrome 52, a website I'm working on renders columns incorrectly. I use the `display: inline-block` 'hack' to force column break/force the flow of text. It used to work fine in the latest browsers (Chrome, Firefox, IE 11), but stopped working as of Chrome 52. Version 51 was fine.

[image: Illustration]

FF and IE nicely split the columns, Chrome 52 displays only 1 column.

I tried using `display: table;` without much success.

```css
.text-2-col {
  -ms-column-count: 2;
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  -moz-column-count: 2;
  column-count: 2;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
}

.text-2-col .column {
  display: inline-block; 
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="text-2-col" style="font-size: 1.4rem;">
  <span class="column"><b>Where we went, what we did:</b>
  <br>
  <b>1.day</b>
  <br>
  <ul>
    <li>Took a ride from Keflavik airport through Akranes around Akrafjall to our accomodation in the north.&nbsp;</li>
    <li>On the way we stopped by at the Kolugljúfur waterfall and Pingeyrar chuch. Around 11 p.m., during our 'night' hike, we saw an artic fox behind our house.</li>
  </ul>
  <b>2.day</b>
  <br>
  <ul>
    <li>Took a ride around the Siglufjörður, a small fishing town on the northern coast, where we had a quick stop, and then through the second largest city in Iceland - Akureyri</li>
    <li>We visited Glaumbær &nbsp;- Skagafjörður Folk Museum and had a cake and a cup of coffee in a lovely cafe in a traditional house nearby.</li>
    <li>Then we went to see the Goðafoss, one of the most spectacular waterfalls in Iceland.</li>
  </ul>
  </span>
  <span class="column"><b>3.day</b>
  <br>
  <ul>
    <li>ay of whales and puffins! Early in the morning we went to Husavik and took a boat to observe the whales and puffins. I saw the tail and white belly of a whale and bunch of puffins. Our boat-guide told us not to eat any whale or puffin, because of the quickly decreasing number of whales living in the ocean around Iceland, and I agreed. Nice guy, I thought.</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>Later that day we hiked Krafla vulcano and saw a nice Viti Crater along the way. But the highlight of the day came only in the evening -- bathing in Mývatn Nature Baths -- eutrophic lake situated in an area of active volcano activity. That was the best time on Iceland for me. Steaming natural water, fresh air, bathing till late at night. What could be better?</li>
  </ul>
  <b>4.day</b>
  <br>
  <ul>
    <li>Day of lava! Went to the Leirhnjukur Lava Fields and Hverir steam fields. There was a collection of steam fumaroles, some bubbling mud pots and lots of interesting colours.</li>
    <li>Took a ride to the east - our next accomodation at Gíslastaðir awaits.</li>
  </ul>
  </span>
</div>
```

Relevant CodePen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wWkWgp

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an older question, but I had a similar problem, and wanted to use column-rule, so using flex wasn't an option.
My solution at the moment is to use a media query for webkit:

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 0) {
  .text-2-col .column {
    display: block; 
    -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;      
  }
}
```

I've updated the codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yoyWVW

Answer (score 2):

I came across this issue today, to fix it I ended up wrapping the columns in a block element such that:

```
.text-2-col {
  -ms-column-count: 2;
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  -moz-column-count: 2;
  column-count: 2;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
}

.text-2-col .column {
  display: inline-block; 
  width: 100%;
}
<div class="text-2-col" style="font-size: 1.4rem;">
  <span class="column">{...}</span>
  <span class="column">{...}</span>
</div>
```

becomes

```
.text-2-col {
  -ms-column-count: 2;
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  -moz-column-count: 2;
  column-count: 2;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
}

.text-2-col .column {
  display: inline-block; 
  width: 100%;
}
<div class="text-2-col" style="font-size: 1.4rem;">
  <div class="column-container">
    <span class="column">{...}</span>
  </div>
  <div class="column-container">
    <span class="column">{...}</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

And it has certainly done the trick for my issue tested in latest Chrome and FF.

Comment: This solution makes absolutely zero sense to me, but it worked for me too.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove:

```
.text-2-col .column {
  display: inline-block; 
  width: 100%;
}
```

And it works as expected.

```css
.text-2-col {
  -ms-column-count: 2;
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  -moz-column-count: 2;
  column-count: 2;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="text-2-col" style="font-size: 1.4rem;">
  <span class="column">
<b>
  Where we went, what we did:
 </b>
 <br>
<b>
  1.day
 </b>
 <br>
<ul>
<li>
   Took a ride from Keflavik airport through Akranes around Akrafjall to our accomodation in the north.&nbsp;
  </li>
<li>
  On the way we stopped by at the Kolugljúfur waterfall and Pingeyrar chuch. Around 11 p.m., during our 'night' hike, we saw an artic fox behind our house.
  </li>
</ul>
<b>
  2.day
 </b>
 <br>
<ul>
<li>
   Took a ride around the Siglufjörður, a small fishing town on the northern coast, where we had a quick stop, and then through the second largest city in Iceland - Akureyri
  </li>
<li>
   We visited Glaumbær &nbsp;- Skagafjörður Folk Museum and had a cake and a cup of coffee in a lovely cafe in a traditional house nearby.
  </li>
<li>
   Then we went to see the Goðafoss, one of the most spectacular waterfalls in Iceland.
  </li>
</ul>
</span>



  <span class="column">
<b>
  3.day
 </b>
 <br>
<ul>
<li>
   Day of whales and puffins! Early in the morning we went to Husavik and took a boat to observe the whales and puffins. I saw the tail and white belly of a whale and bunch of puffins. Our boat-guide told us not to eat any whale or puffin, because of the quickly decreasing number of whales living in the ocean around Iceland, and I agreed. Nice guy, I thought.
  </li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li>
   Later that day we hiked Krafla vulcano and saw a nice Viti Crater along the way. But the highlight of the day came only in the evening -- bathing in Mývatn Nature Baths -- eutrophic lake situated in an area of active volcano activity. That was the best time on Iceland for me. Steaming natural water, fresh air, bathing till late at night. What could be better?
  </li>
</ul>
<b>4.day</b>
 <br>
<ul>
<li>Day of lava! Went to the Leirhnjukur Lava Fields and Hverir steam fields. There was a collection of steam fumaroles, some bubbling mud pots and lots of interesting colours.</li>
<li>Took a ride to the east - our next accomodation at Gíslastaðir awaits.</li>
</ul>
</span>
</div>
```

---

Alternatively, you can use `flexbox`.

```css
.text-2-col {
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  display: flex;
}
.text-2-col .column {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="text-2-col" style="font-size: 1.4rem;">
  <span class="column">
<b>
  Where we went, what we did:
 </b>
 <br>
<b>
  1.day
 </b>
 <br>
<ul>
<li>
   Took a ride from Keflavik airport through Akranes around Akrafjall to our accomodation in the north.&nbsp;
  </li>
<li>
  On the way we stopped by at the Kolugljúfur waterfall and Pingeyrar chuch. Around 11 p.m., during our 'night' hike, we saw an artic fox behind our house.
  </li>
</ul>
<b>
  2.day
 </b>
 <br>
<ul>
<li>
   Took a ride around the Siglufjörður, a small fishing town on the northern coast, where we had a quick stop, and then through the second largest city in Iceland - Akureyri
  </li>
<li>
   We visited Glaumbær &nbsp;- Skagafjörður Folk Museum and had a cake and a cup of coffee in a lovely cafe in a traditional house nearby.
  </li>
<li>
   Then we went to see the Goðafoss, one of the most spectacular waterfalls in Iceland.
  </li>
</ul>
</span>



  <span class="column">
<b>
  3.day
 </b>
 <br>
<ul>
<li>
   Day of whales and puffins! Early in the morning we went to Husavik and took a boat to observe the whales and puffins. I saw the tail and white belly of a whale and bunch of puffins. Our boat-guide told us not to eat any whale or puffin, because of the quickly decreasing number of whales living in the ocean around Iceland, and I agreed. Nice guy, I thought.
  </li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li>
   Later that day we hiked Krafla vulcano and saw a nice Viti Crater along the way. But the highlight of the day came only in the evening -- bathing in Mývatn Nature Baths -- eutrophic lake situated in an area of active volcano activity. That was the best time on Iceland for me. Steaming natural water, fresh air, bathing till late at night. What could be better?
  </li>
</ul>
<b>4.day</b>
 <br>
<ul>
<li>Day of lava! Went to the Leirhnjukur Lava Fields and Hverir steam fields. There was a collection of steam fumaroles, some bubbling mud pots and lots of interesting colours.</li>
<li>Took a ride to the east - our next accomodation at Gíslastaðir awaits.</li>
</ul>
</span>
</div>
```